# Cannot ping second IP on same NIC

Tags: networking, router, vmware-workstation

So I have decided to get into running a home server running Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5 (DHCP, DNS and AD DS) in VMWare using a bridged connection to a router without any internet access. Because both IPs (the VM and my host's second ethernet port) are on the same NIC, will this prevent me from communicating between the computers? Both computers can ping the router but cannot ping each other. External device can ping the VM but not the host.